# Is there an equivalent to the Swing CardLayout in the Qt Framework?

Tags: java, qt, cardlayout

I am designing an Application using the Qt framework, and I want to avoid using multiple dialogs simply because I think it can get messy with having many dialogs open. I was wondering if there was something like Java's CardLayout in the Qt Framework.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`QStackedWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) is very close to the CardLayout

> The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one
>   widget is visible at a time.

Add as many widgets as you want and every time you load it you can change the widget that is displayed by calling the [`setCurrentIndex`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop)

Comment: Hmmm....yes, but from the Documentation, it doesn't seem as though you can layout the widgets in a specified way. I'll play around with this and see how it goes.